# How can I boost performance on my Lenovo C40?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, touchscreen

I have a Lenovo C40-05 
specs are Lenovo C40-05 21.5-Inch All-in-One Touchscreen Desktop (AMD A6 1.8 GHz, 8GB DDR3 RAM, 1TB Hard Drive

Can I put a better video card in it? It had a built in Radeon R4.

Barely plays any decent games. Any suggestions?

Comment: One obvious and universal performance enhancer is to swap your hard disk with an SSD. It seriously improves responsiveness of your machine.

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add there output of "lspci -knn | grep VGA -A2" command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your processor (CPU) is too weak at 1.8 GHz to play heavy games. But upgrades to a better graphics card (GPU) and a solid state drive (SSD) could help to make your laptop faster. The 64 bit version of Ubuntu also improves the performance a bit.

However, I don't think you should go ahead with replacing your CPU. The hassle won't be worth it, and your cooling (fans) will not keep up. The question is even if you can replace your CPU. So try installing an SSD, using the 64 bit Ubuntu and probably a new graphics card.

Comment: Agree. I have recently changed my HD with an SSD it a few days ago and it feels like a completely different computer. For gaming, loading times will be (way) better but you probably will not gain a single FPS though. Maybe a new graphics card would help, but the CPU is slow too... I'd go for another PC, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You say it *had* an AMD graphics card in it (and [the product page](http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/desktops/lenovo/c-series/c40-05/#tab-tech_specs) confirms this) - did you take it out, or are you just mistakenly referring to it in a *past-tense*?

If the AMD graphics card is stand-alone (which as I understand it, it is), there's no reason why you *couldn't* upgrade the graphics card... But due to the design (which offers limited space), you'll probably find that only a *laptop* graphics card will physically fit ("all-in-ones" rarely use "regular" graphics cards)...

A little more expensive, but they fit, they're designed to use less power and in terms of performance, your only real limitation is your budget.

An SSD (solid state drive) and if you're running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu (Unity Dash-->Details-->OS type), more RAM (memory) will also increase your performance somewhat... Additional RAM (memory) will make the computer faster in general (though I wouldn't go beyond 16GB unless you've got money to waste - it's a waste outside of specific usage scenarios), and an SSD will significantly shorten load times of the computer, it's programs and files (they're expensive though).